# VBA how to give a table in Excel a custom table style

Tags: excel, vba

simple question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere so I'll put it here: how to you assign table styles to tables, yet not map it to a default table style i.e. make custom style elements? I read it might involve `.TableStyleElements` but when I tried to add `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyleElements(xlHeaderRow).Font.Color = RGB(119, 184, 0)` it breaks. Am I getting the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to declare the table style first eg:

```
Dim oTblStyle As TableStyle

Set oTblStyle = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle

oTblStyle.TableStyleElements.Item(xlHeaderRow).Font.Color = RGB(119, 184, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason when it got to `oTblStyle.TableStyleElements.Item(xlHeaderRow).Font.Color = RGB(119, 184, 0)` it gave me a Runtime error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: I've edited the answer to ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle - had you already amended that in your code anyway?

Comment: Yeah, the debug is ok with that line, even after amending it. It's still finding a problem with that last line

Comment: there seems to be a bug when setting the font color. oTblStyle.TableStyleElements.Item(xlHeaderRow).Font.Bold = False works fine and you can also read the property of Font.Color... very strange

Comment: I think it has to do with a preset table style that I had on my existing table, because once I removed that style I got a '424' error: Object Required